# Javascript : multiple remainder pricing table

Tags: javascript

I have been given this logic table that I need to use if else statement to get a promotion price based on user input.

How to declare that logic table in javascript? So that I can print out the correct output based on the table.

For example; if user input is 5, so, I need an expected output of (price 3 + price 2).

[image]

```js
function checkQuantity() {
  let userInput = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
  userInput = Number(userInput); //Convert string to number data type

  var pizzaPrice = 6.45;
  var pizzaPrice2 = 12.00;
  var pizzaPrice3 = 14.00;


  if (!userInput) {
    console.log("Please enter a valid pizza quantity");

  } else if (isNaN(userInput)) {
    console.log("Error!!");

  } else if (userInput < 1) {
    console.log("Minimum pizza order is 1.");

  } else {
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Number of pizza : ' + //Price hasn't been declared yet;
  }

  return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ordering form</title>
    <script src="linked.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>PizzasOnly ordering form</h1>
<p>Simply enter the number of pizzas you want into the input below to find out the cost of your order</p>

<form action="#" method="post" id="orderForm" onsubmit="return checkQuantity()">
    <p>
        <label for="quantity">Enter number of pizzas wanted:</label>
        <input name="quantity" id="quantity" value="">

    </p>
    <p>
        <input value="Total cost" type="submit">

    </p>
</form>
    <div id="message"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry, I wanna ask, how to declare that logic table in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula can be assembled as a one-liner:

```
~~(i/3)*price + xtra[i%3]
```

`~~` (the repeated application of the "bitwise NOT operator") is a shorthand notation for `Math(floor()`, `%` is the modulo operator that will return the remainder of a division, the rest should be clear.

```js
const price=(i,p3=14,xtr=[0,6.45,12])=>~~(i/3)*p3 + xtr[i%3];

[...Array(14)].map((_,i)=>i+1).concat([50,100,1500,1276]).forEach(i=>console.log(i,price(i)) )
```

In this later version I defined the function `price()`. It can be called with one argument (`i`: number of pizzas) as you can see above.

The optional arguments `p3` (price for a bundle of 3) and `xtr` (addon for zero, one or two extra pizzas) can be supplied if you want to use a different pricing structure than the default one, see here:

```js
const price=(i,p3=14,xtr=[0,6.45,12])=>~~(i/3)*p3 + xtr[i%3];

[...Array(14)].map((_,i)=>i+1).concat([50,100,1500,1276]).forEach(i=>console.log(i,price(i,16,[0,6,11])) )
```

Comment: Thank you @cars10m. I didn't come across to use math.floor